# как в gatsby netlify-cms настроить backend в config.yml с субдоменом gitlab

Tags: gitlab, yml

необходимо связать репозиторий гитлаба с neetlify cms gatsby

как в gatsby netlify-cms настроить config.yml backend=>name  под нестандартный gitlab домен?

так работает для обычного гитлаба
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но не работает с кастомным субдоменом[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: извиняюсь) думал , что это один и тот же сайт, не могу настроить бекенд в  gatsby netlify cms config.yml под кастомный субдомен gitlab